# Как задать один цвет текста в UIStatusBar и UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, ios7

Как задать одинаковый цвет текста в NavigationBar и в StatusBar (включая цвет значков уровня батареи, сигнала и т. д.) как в приложении FaceBook?
Пока могу менять только цвет текста в NavigationBar по отдельности

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У `StatusBar` нельзя изменять цвет текста, он может быть черным или белым в зависимости от стиля `StatusBar`

Стиль меняется следующим образом:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

при этом в `Info.plist` надо добавить `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance NO`